# Javascript Comparison Weird

Tags: javascript

I got into the problem with the comparison. The result supposes to be 11 as the cost of products at index 11 is less than the cost of the product at index 18. But somehow the result is 18

```
    var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
    41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
    var costs = [.25, .27, .25, .25, .25, .25, .33, .31, .25, .29, .27, .22, .31, .25, .25, .33, .21, .25, .25, .25, .28, .25, .24, .22, .20, .25, .30, .25, .24, .25,
        .25, .25, .27, .25, .26, .29];
//TOTAL, HIGHEST, INDEX OF THE HIGHEST
function index(array,arrayCost){
    var maximum=Math.max(...array);
    var arrayIndex=[];
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i]==maximum){
            arrayIndex.push(i)
        }
    }

   var minimum=arrayCost[arrayIndex[0]];//0.22
   for(var i=0;i<arrayIndex.length;i++){
       if(arrayCost[arrayIndex[i]]<=minimum){//0.25>=0.22
           minimum=arrayIndex[i];
       }
   }
    return minimum;
}
```

Comment: Should be `minimum=arrayCost[arrayIndex[i]]`

Comment: It couldn't be arrayCost[arrayIndex[i]] because you have to assign a value for minimum so that you can compare it with other values in the array. Moreover, you haven't declared the variable I yet so likely the result is undefined.

Comment: .... I meant the part that you now have as `minimum=arrayIndex[i];` should be changed

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The bug really comes from there:))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `if`, you reassign `minimum` with `arrayIndex[i]` that values is `11`, so at the next loop minimum will be `11` and `arrayCost[arrayIndex[i]]` will be less than `11`.
You can create another variable that stores the `index` value.

```js
function index(array, arrayCost) {
  var maximum = Math.max(...array);
  var arrayIndex = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == maximum) {
      arrayIndex.push(i);
    }
  }

  var resultIndex = arrayIndex[0];
  var minimumCost = arrayCost[arrayIndex[0]]; //0.22
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayIndex.length; i++) {
    if (arrayCost[arrayIndex[i]] <= minimumCost) {
      //0.25>=0.22
      minimumCost = arrayCost[arrayIndex[i]];
      resultIndex = arrayIndex[i];
    }
  }
  return resultIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your bug is shown in the comments, but I'd rework it to use a single loop:

```js
var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
    41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
    var costs = [.25, .27, .25, .25, .25, .25, .33, .31, .25, .29, .27, .22, .31, .25, .25, .33, .21, .25, .25, .25, .28, .25, .24, .22, .20, .25, .30, .25, .24, .25,
        .25, .25, .27, .25, .26, .29];


function index(array, arrayCost) {
  var maxScore = Math.max(...array);
  var minCostIndex = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayCost.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] != maxScore) {
      continue;
    }
    if (minCostIndex == null || arrayCost[i] < arrayCost[minCostIndex]) {
      minCostIndex = i;
    }
  }

  return minCostIndex;
}

console.log("res", index(scores, costs));
```

---

You could even eliminate the `Math.max` if you wanted:

```js
var scores = [60, 50, 60, 58, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69, 34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46, 31, 57, 52, 44, 18,
    41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44];
    var costs = [.25, .27, .25, .25, .25, .25, .33, .31, .25, .29, .27, .22, .31, .25, .25, .33, .21, .25, .25, .25, .28, .25, .24, .22, .20, .25, .30, .25, .24, .25,
        .25, .25, .27, .25, .26, .29];


function index(array, arrayCost) {
  var maxScore = array[0];
  var minCostIndex = 0;
  
  // start iteration at 1, since 0 is accounted for in the vars
  for (var i = 1; i < arrayCost.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > maxScore) {
      maxScore = array[i];
      minCostIndex = i;
      continue
    }

    if (array[i] == maxScore && arrayCost[i] < arrayCost[minCostIndex]) {
      minCostIndex = i;
    }
  }

  return minCostIndex;
}

console.log("res", index(scores, costs));
```